# unable to create mount point in databricks for adls gen 2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create mount point to the ADLS Gen2 using key vault in databricks, however i am not being able to do so due to some error that i am getting.
I have contributor access and i tried with Storage Blob Data Contributor and contributor access to the SPN still i am not being able to create it the mount points.

I request some help please

```
configs= {"fs.azure.account.auth.type":"OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id":"abcdefgh",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret":dbutils.secrets.get(scope="myscope",key="mykey"),
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
        source= "abfss://cont1@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/",
        mount_point="/mnt/cont1",
        extra_configs=configs)
```

the error i am getting is
An error occurred while calling o280.mount.
: HEAD https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/cont1?resource=filesystem&timeout=90
StatusCode=403
StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

> When performing the steps in the Assign the application to a role, make sure that your user account has the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role assigned to it.

**Repro:** I have provided owner permission to the service principal and tried to run the “`dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/azure/")`”, returned same error message as above.

[image]

**Solution:** Now assigned the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the service principal.

[image]

Finally, able to get the output without any error message after assigning the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Tutorial: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure Databricks & Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark)”.

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have a similar issue.

Comment: I did the same as well. I provided Storage Blob Data Contributor to the SPN still i am getting the same error. This is happening in my client id shared to us. However i don't get the same from my personal azure account when the same code is executed.